# Permission denied creating project with GCP resource manager API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-resource-manager

I am trying to create projects programatically through the resource manager API from a google cloud function like so:

```js
exports.createProjectAsync = async (projectId, projectName) => {
    const scopes = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"
    const url = `http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/token?scopes=${scopes}`
    const tokenResult = await fetch(url, {
        headers: {
            "Metadata-Flavor": "Google"
        },
    });
    const tokenStatus = tokenResult.status;
    functions.logger.log(`Call to get token has status ${tokenStatus}`);
    const tokenData = await tokenResult.json()
    functions.logger.log(`Call to get token has data ${JSON.stringify(tokenData)}`);
    const accessToken = tokenData.access_token;
    if (accessToken === null) {
        throw new Error(`Failed to retrieve access token`);
    }
    const headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`
    };
    const payload = {
        "projectId": projectId,
        "name": projectName,
        "parent": {
            "type": "folder",
            "id": FOLDER_NUMBER
        }
    };
    const projectsCreateUrl = `https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/`
    const result = await fetch(projectsCreateUrl, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: headers,
        body: JSON.stringify(payload)
    });
    const status = result.status;
    functions.logger.log(`Call to create project returned status ${status}`);
    const data = await result.json()
    functions.logger.log(`data: ${JSON.stringify(data)}`);
    return data;
}
```

For testing purposes I've added the Organization Administrator role to the default service account. I cannot see the projects creator role in IAM:

[image]

When calling the API I get the following error:

`{"error":{"code":403,"message":"The caller does not have permission","status":"PERMISSION_DENIED"}}`

How can I successfully access this resource?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although of course, it gives you the ability to modify its own permissions, as you can verify in the [GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#resource-manager-roles), the `Organization Admin` role does not allow to create a new project.

As you indicated, for that purpose the service account should be granted the `Project Creator` (`roles/resourcemanager.projectCreator`) role.

According to your screenshot, you are trying to grant this permission at the project level, but please, be aware that this role can only be granted at the organization and folder levels. This is the reason why the dropdown menu in the Google Cloud Web console is not providing you the `Project Creator` option.

If you have the necessary permissions over the folder or organization, try to assign that role at the corresponding level.

Comment: My understanding is that service accounts exist at the project level. Is it possible to assign roles/resourcemanager.projectCreator to a service account at the organization/folder level? I cannot figure out how to do this in GCP console. I have full access.

Comment: Good question @Ollie. Please, let me check It out, just a moment.

Comment: You are right, service accounts are created at the project level, but you can assign permissions to them at the organization or folder level as well. Please, copy the id (email address) of the service account you want to grant the project creator role, select the organization or a folder, and from the IAM menu, add the service account by pasting it (probably you can search for it as well). You should have the ability to do that. At least it should work for user defined service accounts. Please, can you try? Very good point @Ollie.

Comment: Thank you! This worked. The reason I found it confusing is that the service account is not auto populated when adding it at the organization level. To clarify, I went to IAM & admin with the organization selected > add user > paste in service account email > add projects creator role.

Comment: You are welcome @Ollie. Yes, it is a bit confusing indeed. Thank you very much for the clarification. Please, do not hesitate to contact me if you need further help.